# Pandas groupby multiple columns and retain all other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which is the `concat` of two identically structured df's, the first is `Orders` and the second is `Cancels`.
There are more than 20,000 rows in `Orders` and a small number of `Cancels` that have a corresponding `OrderNo` & `ItemCode`. I have made the canceled quantities negative, so that while grouping the df by both `OrderNo` & `ItemCode` I can sum the quantity fields with `agg`, thus giving me the actual quantity shipped which compensates for canceled orders.

Below is my dataframe:

```
    OrderNo     OrderDate   LineNo  ClientNo    ItemCode    QtyOrdered  QtyShipped
0   528758  1/3/2017    1   1358538     111931  70  70
1   528791  1/3/2017    10  1254798     110441  300     300
2   528791  1/3/2017    1   1254798     1029071     10  10
3   528791  1/3/2017    2   1254798     1033341     10  10
4   528791  1/3/2017    8   1254798     1040726     15  15
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
28344   537667  2/6/2017    12  43823870    10137992    0   -2
28345   537771  2/7/2017    5   1276705     1041106     0   -4
28346   539524  2/13/2017   6   1254798     1038323     0   -10
28347   542362  2/23/2017   11  1254612     1041108     0   -2
28348   542835  2/23/2017   13  1255235     10137993    0   -5

28349 rows × 7 columns
```

After running:

```
ActualOrders = PreActualOrders.groupby(['OrderNo','ItemCode']).agg({'QtyOrdered': 'sum', 'QtyShipped': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

I get my desired result but i lose all other columns in the DF.

Result sample below:

```
    OrderNo     ItemCode    QtyOrdered  QtyShipped
28255   543734  1038324     1   1
28256   543734  10137992    1   1
28257   543734  10137993    1   1
28258   543735  1041106     1   1
28259   543735  1041108     1   1
28260   543735  10135359    1   1
```

What do I need to add inorder to keep all columns in the original df?

All values in those other columns match as they are corresponding cancels or the order.

Thank you,

MTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by including the other columns in the `agg` funtion with `'first'` while the 'QtyOrdered' & 'QtyShipped' are subject to `'sum'`.

`ActualOrders = PreActualOrders.groupby(['OrderNo','ItemCode']).agg({'OrderDate': 'first', 'LineNo': 'first', 'ClientNo': 'first', 'QtyOrdered': 'sum', 'QtyShipped': 'sum' }).reset_index()`

Yeilds my desired reult of:

```
      OrderNo   ItemCode    OrderDate LineNo ClientNo QtyOrdered QtyShipped
28255   543734  1038324     2/27/2017   3   1254787     1   1
28256   543734  10137992    2/27/2017   1   1254787     1   1
28257   543734  10137993    2/27/2017   2   1254787     1   1
28258   543735  1041106     2/27/2017   4   1816460     1   1
28259   543735  1041108     2/27/2017   3   1816460     1   1
28260   543735  10135359    2/27/2017   2   1816460     1   1
28261   543735  10137993    2/27/2017   1   1816460     1   1
```

The output example doesn't show any difference between Qty ordered and shipped because the number of matching cancels is very small. The rows which have a corresponding cancel are correctly adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could maybe try another approach without groupby.
Something similar to this:

```
orders = [["123", "1", 10], ["1234", "2", 100], ["12345", "3", 15]]
cancels = [["123", "1", 10]]

df_orders = pd.DataFrame(orders, columns=["OrderNo", "ItemCode", "Amount"])
df_cancels = pd.DataFrame(cancels, columns=["OrderNo", "ItemCode", "Amount"])

merged = df_orders.merge(df_cancels, how="left", on=["OrderNo", "ItemCode"], suffixes=["_orders", "_cancels"])
merged["Amount_cancels"] = merged["Amount_cancels"].fillna(0)
print("Before substract cancels")
print(merged)

merged["Amount_orders"] = merged["Amount_orders"] - merged["Amount_cancels"]
print("After substract cancels")
print(merged)
```